# C# sending integer using server sockets

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, client-server

How do you send integer values via server sockets? 
Sending strings is fairly easy since that is what is being covered in the MDN tutorials.

Comment: What? What do you mean "send"? What code are you using to "send" an integer that's throwing an error?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_pigeon

Comment: Create a WCf service http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2007/10/15/how-to-create-a-hello-world-wcf-service-using-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it to a string, XML, or any other format you wish.  Or, if you want to send just the bytes of the integer, you can convert the integer to a byte array like this:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(integer);
```

However, if you do that, you must be careful of the byte-order on both ends of the communication (big endian vs. little endian).

Answer (score 0):

How about converting it to string, and in the end you mostly send a byte array

Comment: converting (parsing) an integer to its string representation to then convert it into a byte array is not the same as converting an integer into byte array directly.